# Minimum implementation of a bare pass through Media Foundation Audio MFT for Windows RT

Tags: windows-runtime, ms-media-foundation

I have searched the web, different forums and MS Windows 8 app samples but I only find either results that go way over my head or questions of users who want - just as myself - do very simple tasks like observing raw PCM audio (or any other sample passing through the topology) for analysis but don't really get any other answer than look at this or that sample.

The problem with these samples is, that they do too much and a noob like me, does not find the first "easy" entry into the topic.

So my question: 
Has anybody got a realy bare, minimum, pass through MFT implementation or even better template that can be plugged into the MF topology?

Having this, I think a lot of users who asked the second group of questions - like myself - could easier grasp what's the real core of the topic without having to understand a complex sample, reduce it to its essence and than start building what they actually intend to do.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Nothing new? No ideas anyone?

Comment: Some one else is looking for something similar at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14390476/draw-waveform-from-mp3-stream-in-c-sharp-on-winrt/14982444#14982444 - is there no one to help us?

Comment: I'd start with this: http://mfnet.sourceforge.net/ (assuming that MediaFoundation is available in the Win8 profile)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is very old, but I was recently looking to answer this same question, so:

Regarding wanting a simple sample: I'm afraid the answer I am about to present is about as simple as you will find...  Microsoft Media foundation is a complicated API, and you need to understand C++ and COM development, along with coming to grips with the asynchronous event-driven nature of the API. Sorry, but that's the nature of the beast.

In the Anton Pollinger Book "Developing Microsoft Media Foundation Transforms", Chapter 5 presents a sample MFT called the "Image Injector MFT", which adds an image on top of a video stream.  There are several comments in the chapter indicating that this is a good place to start for a simple pass through component, for example on page 108:

> In many ways, CImageInjectorMFT is a pass-through component -- it does not make any fundamental changes to the data passing through it...

The sample code for the book can be freely downloaded from the [Microsoft Press page for the book](https://www.microsoftpressstore.com/store/developing-microsoft-media-foundation-applications-9780735656598).  You are interested in the chapter 5 sample.

Regarding wanting a Windows RT solution, I believe that you build always build MFTs in a C++ project, the output of which is a DLL file that is registered with the COM system via  RegSvr32, and is then available to Windows RT applications.  There may be additional constraints on this, but as I develop for Win32 currently, I do not know for sure.