# Draw waveform from MP3 stream in C# on WinRT

Tags: c#, .net, windows-runtime, mp3, waveform

I'm working on a Windows RT App that uses MediaCapture.StartRecordToStreamAsync() to capture the audio stream in MP3 format (16 bit, 44.1 KHz, 128Kbps). I was wondering if anyone knows how to effectively convert the stream into a float array that can be drawn onto a canvas.

I already found a way of converting the MP3 to PCM using some Interop calls, and then reading the wave to draw the waveform. But I guess I'm looking for a way to draw the waveform from the stream that generates MediaCapture directly.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!